# trouble inputting parsed data into struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am taking a C++ class and on this project I have run into a wall.
I am supposed to accept input from the user in the form of MM/DD/YYYY and then manipulate it in a few ways all using a struct. I have tried several different methods of assigning the variables in the struct but I am never able to get them to represent any value

I have tried getline(cin, data);
as well as gets();

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct date
{
    string day;
    string month;
    string year;
} pinfo;
string RunAgain;
int main()
{
    struct date user;
    while (1)
    {
        string user_entry;
        cout << "Please enter date in the form of MM/DD/YYYY ";
        getline(cin, user_entry);


        string str = user_entry;

        // month is from position 0, to until first / found
        pinfo.month = str.substr(0, str.find("/", 0));
        str = str.substr(str.find("/", 0) + 1, str.length()); // new string
        user.month = pinfo.month;


        // dsy is from position 0 to until first / found
        pinfo.day = str.substr(0, str.find("/", 0));
        str = str.substr(str.find("/", 0) + 1, str.length()); // new string
        user.day = pinfo.day;

        //  Year is from position 0, to until "\n" found
        pinfo.year = str.substr(0, str.find("\n", 0));
        str = str.substr(str.find("\n", 0) + 1, str.length()); // new str                                                                       
        user.year = pinfo.year;


        string month_alpha;

        // error check user entry 
        if (user.month > "12" || user.month < "1")
        {
            cout << " Invalid entry months must be 1-12";
        }


        // convert numeric month to alpha 
        if (pinfo.month == "01")
        {
            month_alpha = "January";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "02")
        {
            month_alpha = "febuary";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "03")
        {
            month_alpha = "March";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "04")
        {
            month_alpha = "April";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "05")
        {
            month_alpha = "May";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "06")
        {
            month_alpha = "June";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "07")
        {
            month_alpha = "July";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "08")
        {
            month_alpha = "August";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "09")
        {
            month_alpha = "September";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "10")
        {
            month_alpha = "October";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "11")
        {
            month_alpha = "November";
        }

        else if (pinfo.month == "12")
        {
            month_alpha = "December";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Entry";
        }

        // check day range
        if (pinfo.month == "1" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of January";

        }
        if (pinfo.month == "2" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of Febuary";
            int number = atoi(pinfo.year.c_str());

            if (pinfo.month == "2" && number % 4 == 0)
            {
                cout << pinfo.year << " -> Leap Year!";

            }
            if (pinfo.month == "3" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))

                cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of March";
        }

        if (pinfo.month == "3" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of March";
        }

        if (pinfo.month == "4" && (pinfo.day > "30" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of April";
        }
        if (pinfo.month == "5" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of May";
        }
        if (pinfo.month == "6" && (pinfo.day > "30" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of June";
        }
        if (pinfo.month == "7" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of July";
        }
        if (pinfo.month == "8" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of August";
        }
        if (pinfo.month == "" && (pinfo.day > "30" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of September";
        }
        if (pinfo.month == "1" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of October";
        }
        if (pinfo.month == "1" && (pinfo.day > "30" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of November";
        }
        if (pinfo.month == "12" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))
        {
            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of December";
        }

        // prints month, day, year 
        cout << pinfo.month << ", " << pinfo.day << ", " << pinfo.year << month_alpha << "(US) \n";
        cout << month_alpha << " " << pinfo.day << ", " << pinfo.year << "(US Expanded) \n";
        cout << pinfo.day << " " << month_alpha << " " << pinfo.year << "(US Military) \n";
        cout << pinfo.year << "-" << pinfo.day << "month_alpha" << "-" << "(International) \n";

        RunAgain = "x";
        while (RunAgain != "y" && RunAgain != "n")
        {
            cout << "Run Again (y/n)? \n" << endl;
            getline(cin, RunAgain);
        }

        // Program Exit 

        if (RunAgain == "n")
        {
            cout << "Programmer: Christopher Dresser \n\nGoodbye! Press <Enter> key to end the program... ";
            getline(cin, RunAgain);
            if (RunAgain.empty())
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is very complicated because you use strings for numeric values and because there are a lot of tests for nothing without any else (if you know you are in a given month why to check if you are in others after ?). You also check `pinfo.day < "1"` for all the months, to do only one time is enough.

There are also some error like

> ```
>    if (pinfo.month == "2" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))
> ```

in February there are never 31 days and if the test above is true indicating an error in February you do anyway

> ```
>        int number = atoi(pinfo.year.c_str());
>
>        if (pinfo.month == "2" && number % 4 == 0)
>        {
>            cout << pinfo.year << " -> Leap Year!" << endl;
>
>        }
>        if (pinfo.month == "3" && (pinfo.day > "31" || pinfo.day < "1"))
>
>            cout << pinfo.day << "is not a valid day of March" << endl;
> ```

so you test the leap case too late and you also check the case of Mars (copy/paste error probably).

I encourage you to transform the day and month in numbers and to have an array containing the max possible number of days / month name at the index corresponding to the month more the special management of February if you just want an approximation, else use the available lib to check.

When you print an error message flush it with a newline else the next print is collapsed to it.

You way to run again or not is also complicated, and why to abort the exit if the final line enter through *getline* is not empty ?